# Why sscanf(3) accepts a NULL pointer as pointer argument for %s conversion?

Tags: c

I was hunting a bug in one of our C-written application servers which was found later in some unexpected place. The reason of "later" was/is that sscanf(3) silently accepts a NULL pointer as argument for a %s conversion. I have here a short gdb session of the situation:

```
Breakpoint 1, main () at SRP-32744.c:10
10        strcpy(name, "Mack, Anna");
(gdb) n
12        pHelp=(char *) NULL;
(gdb) n
13        sscanf(name, "%s", pHelp);
(gdb) p pHelp
$1 = 0x0
(gdb) n
15        printf("after sscanf()\n");
```

I'd have expected a SIGSEGV in sscanf(3), but no, it silently does not do any conversion (and the application crashed later when the pointer pHelp was used as a source for a strcpy(3)).
Why is this?

Comment: So long story short, it's a non standard behavior of gnu libc.

Comment: If your code invokes undefined behaviour, you cannot assume that this will be visible in some specific way. Undefined means that it is not defined whether you get a SIGSEGV or just a wrong result.

Comment: [What is undefined behavior and how does it work?](https://software.codidact.com/posts/277486)

Comment: @vvv444 One wonders what the return value from `sscanf()` is in this case.

Comment: rc = sscanf(name, "%s", NULL);
  printf("after sscanf() with rc=%d\n", rc);

gives on execution:

after sscanf() with rc=0

Answer (score 0):

> Why sscanf(3) accepts a NULL pointer as pointer argument for %s
> conversion?

It's undefined behaviour as per the following rule:

> *Each of the following statements applies unless explicitly stated
> otherwise in the detailed descriptions that follow: If an argument to
> a function has an invalid value (such as a value outside the domain of
> the function, or a pointer outside the address space of the program,
> or a null pointer, or a pointer to non-modifiable storage when the
> corresponding parameter is not const-qualified) or a type (after
> promotion) not expected by a function with variable number of
> arguments, the behavior is undefined. — 7.1.4p1 C18 standard.*

Expecting a `SIGSEGV` is unrealistic. The standard defines undefined behavior as:

> *Possible undefined behavior ranges from ignoring the situation completely with unpredictable results, to behaving during translation
> or program execution in a documented manner characteristic of the
> environment (with or without the issuance of a diagnostic message), to
> terminating a translation or execution (with the issuance of a
> diagnostic message).*

Nowhere does it state that a `SIGSEGV` would be raised (though it may happen).